# Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a dataTable table fed via ajax. And I have a td with details-control, when I destroy this dataTable and create it again, my details-control does not work from the 3 element.
It gives this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined
at t.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:121)
at Function.isShown (jquery.dataTables.min.js:103)
at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (fichaFisica.js:317)
at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLTableElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Would anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code my answer is quite limited. But I assume the problem is that through changes within your HTML, the eventlisteners defined are no longer available as they reference an element that no longer exists.

To overcome that issue you can use jQuery's `on`-method.
This way your defined function will execute for any dynamically added/removed elements like so:

```
$('#yourStaticDiv').on('click', 'yourSelectorOfDynamicElement', function() {
  // Actual code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#tbl_CpseData').find('tbody').off('click', 'tr td.details-control');
                    $('#tbl_CpseData').find('tbody').on('click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var row = oTable.row(tr);

```
                    if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        // This row is already open - close it
                        row.child.hide();
                        tr.removeClass('shown');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Open this row
                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                        tr.addClass('shown');
                    }
                });
```